# Video Player with range selector to clip that part of the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I want to know how can I embed a range slider in a video player in HTML5. This range slider will be used to select the start point and end point of that video and that part of the video will be clipped. I am using ffmpeg to clip the part of the video which is working fine manual input for clipping the video(backend part is complete).

I just want to know how to let user select a portion from any video(video he is playing currently). I am using video.js which does not have rang selecting feature.

Please guide me how to do it. I am thinking of using Jquery ui for range slider but how to embed that with the video.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] because asking for advice is not really considered a good question.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using video.js which does not have rang selecting feature.

It has, at least with this plugin: https://github.com/danielcebrian/rangeslider-videojs